# Ignore records marked as deleted in navigation properties in EF 4.0

Tags: .net, database, entity-framework

I have added a column 'IsDeleted' to every entity in my Entity Framework 4.0 model and implemented an Interface for it. How can i accomplish that the entities with 'IsDeleted' set to 'true' are ignored by all Objectsets and Navigationproperties in my model? Filtering the result using LinQ does not work i think, because the result can not be transformed back into an ObjectSet.

Can anybody help me please?

BTW: My template generates ObjectSets in the context-class like this:

```
Private _Persons As ObjectSet(Of Person)
Public ReadOnly Property Persons() As ObjectSet(Of Person)
    Get
        If (_Persons Is Nothing) Then
            _Persons = MyBase.CreateObjectSet(Of Person)("Persons")
        End If
        Return _Persons
    End Get
End Property
```

and navigation properties for the entities like this one:

```
<XmlIgnoreAttribute()>
<SoapIgnoreAttribute()>
<DataMemberAttribute()>
<EdmRelationshipNavigationPropertyAttribute("Model", "Map_Persons_Organisations", "Persons")>
 Public Property Persons() As EntityCollection(Of Person)
    Get
        Return CType(Me,IEntityWithRelationships).RelationshipManager.GetRelatedCollection(Of Person)("Model.Map_Persons_Organisations", "Persons")
    End Get
    Set
        If (Not value Is Nothing)
            CType(Me, IEntityWithRelationships).RelationshipManager.InitializeRelatedCollection(Of Person)("Model.Map_Persons_Organisations", "Persons", value)
        End If
    End Set
End Property
```

Answer (score -1):

What is the purpose of your IsDeleted flag?  Objects marked for deletion have their status updated by the [ObjectStateManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectstatemanager.aspx).  You can determine if an object has been marked for deletion before `SaveChanges()` has been called by querying the ObjectStateManager.

If you want to exclude deleted entities from your queries, call `SaveChanges()` marking them for deletion..  You can also use `AcceptChanges()` to remove entities from the collection without committing the deletion to the database.

Comment: The purpose is that I don't want to lose the deleted data. It should only not (NEVER) be visible on the GUI. I don't think I can do this with AcceptChanges(). Adding 'WHERE IsDeleted = false' or something to every query is not an option either, because it would be forgotten once in a while.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to implement an "Archived" flag that indicates that an Entity has been "deactivated" and should not be accessible.  That's an application-specific requirement outside EF's scope.  If you don't want to have to filter all your queries on a flag like that, you should consider an Archive method that *copies* "deactivated" entities to an archive table.

Comment: That's a poor response to the problem. I realize this is an old question but it's still a common question and your response essentially says, "I don't care what you're doing - you're doing it wrong" and you are far too ignorant of the situation to make such a claim. What if the design of the system is that the application should not be aware of soft-deleted records and this archival process is done by the database/data team? Then it leads that this is in fact a database-specific concern and they're trying to make their DAL compliant.